# Child directory sizes and owners

Tags: powershell, filesystems

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script retrieving the directory size and owner on my Windows file systems. I've got two separate scripts that work independently, but I don’t know how to put them together as a single script file.

Directory Name and Size:

```
$startFolder = "C:\Test”
$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
foreach ($i in $colItems)
    {
        $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB" 
    }
```

Directory owner:

```
Get-ACL C:\Test
```

I'd like for the script to output to a CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something along the lines of this then?

```powershell
$start = "c:\temp"
$output = "C:\temp\output.csv"
Get-ChildItem $start | Where-Object{$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object{
    $singleFolder = $_.FullName
    $folderSize = Get-ChildItem $singleFolder -Recurse -Force | Where-Object{!$_.PSIsContainer} | Measure-Object -Property length -sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
    $folderSize = [math]::round($folderSize/1MB, 2)
    $owner = Get-Acl $singleFolder | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Owner
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FolderSize -Value $folderSize -PassThru |
        Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Owner -Value $owner -PassThru
} | Select-Object FullName,FolderSize,Owner | Export-Csv $output -NoTypeInformation
```

Needed to add some extra logic in length calculation to keep folders out of the mix > `Where-Object{!$_.PSIsContainer}`. This should work with PowerShell 2.0 just fine.

It loops through each folder in the root of `$start` and for each `$singleFolder` calculates the size of the contents and folder owner.

The variables are then added to object through pipeline with `Add-Member` as the properties `FolderSize` and `Owner`. The final `Select-Object` is used to isolate the properties we want for the output file.

**Sample**

```powershell
FullName                         FolderSize  Owner                 
--------                         ----------  -----                 
C:\temp\37 Place i.Bay                       domain\guy          
C:\temp\adoc42                   1103186357  domain\guy           
C:\temp\Adoc72                   958330505   domain\guy
```

Notice the empty folder. That output is sent to `Export-CSV` in the file `$output`

Comment: Matt, this is really close.  Is there a way to output the folder size in in MB?  I tried to replace part of your script with part of my directory name and size script but it didn't work.

Comment: @KSpinnato updated to add size in MB. All of my code replaces what you have. You just need to change the `$start` and that's it. _but it didn't work_ tells me nothing so I cant help you with that

Comment: I changed your line of code:
    $folderSize = Get-ChildItem $singleFolder -Recurse -Force | Where-Object{!$_.PSIsContainer} | Measure-Object -Property length -sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum

With the part of my original script that output the folder size in MB:
    $folderSize = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        "$startFolder -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

    $folderSize = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)

The output for folder size was:  System.Object[]

Comment: @KSpinnato Reading code in comments can be a strain. Can you tell me what is wrong with the output my script generates? If you have a lot of code you need to show me put it as an edit to the question first.

Comment: Matt,  Your updated script works perfect.  Sorry I missed it on my first reply.  Thanks for your help it getting this problem resolved for me.  Thanks, Kevin